# cc.attrs and cc.attributes, what else?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, xml-namespaces

I'm a beginner regarding JSF and stumbled over this line of code:

```
<ui:param name="notes" value="#{cc.attributes.value}" ></ui:param>
```

I know what `value="#{cc.attributes.value}"` does, but not where the syntax is coming from. So I started to investigate. First thing I found was that I couldn't find the syntax `cc.attributes` via google, only `cc.attrs`

Then my next attempt was to look at URL of the namespace:

```
xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
```

But I couldn't find anything useful there? Which xsd is used for that namespace?

Second thought was that it maybe is part of the Expression Language? And I found out that `cc` is an implicit EL object. But how to proceed from here if I'd like to know what is available under this implicit EL object?

Comment: `xmlns.jcp.org` is a new namespace for JSF 2.2. The old one was `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite`. There are very few tutorials/helps for JSF 2.2, so try search by the old namespace.

Comment: I think you should take a step back and first investigate **when** these are used. You'll most likely find references to 'custom components' or 'composite components' Learn about these and you'll be enlightened

Comment: I'm searching for the official documentation about cc.attrs, cc.clientid etc. but can't find it.